# Got error on using mysqli_real_escape_string in WHERE IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on existing project and there is an abstraction layer on database (previous developers made it and I should not change it).
I extracted functions from abstraction and it looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username IN ({users})";
$users = "alex,john";
$users = str_replace(',', "','", $users);
$users = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $users);
//Here is a replace placeholder function for sql query
...
$query = mysqli_query($dbh, $sql);
```

And I got an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your ?MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\'alex\',\\'john\\')' ?at line 1"

How to correct use `mysqli_real_escape_string` in `WHERE IN` clause?

Comment: As your binding the values, you can drop the `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to prepare your $users variable,

```
$users = "alex,john";
$users=  "'".str_replace(",", "','", $users)."'";
```

**Edit:**

```
 $users_array= explode(',',$users);
 $users= "'". implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $users_array)). "'";
```

Comment: I've tried it already. The same error. I think the problem because of double slashes before quotes  ```\\```

Comment: Did you add the.preceding and trailing quotes?

Comment: Yes, I did it like you suggested.

Comment: Ok, take a look on my edited answer and let me know whether it works for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$users = "alex,john";
$users = "'" . str_replace(',', "','", $users) . "'";
$users = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $users);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username IN ({$users})";

$query = mysqli_query($dbh, $sql);
```

**Recommended** way is to use prepared statements instead and not worry about escaping special characters or SQL injection.

```
$users = "alex,john";
$users = "'" . str_replace(',', "','", $users) . "'";
$sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username IN ({$users})";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $users);

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetch();
```